# why is my chatbot is not sending responses when it does not have an error?

Tags: python, django, chatbot, whatsapp

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.body.decode("utf-8")
        try:
            data_json = json.loads(data)
            response = JsonResponse({'status': 'success'}, status=200)
            Thread(target=process_data, args=(data_json,)).start()
            return response
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            return JsonResponse({'status': 'error', 'message': str(e)}, status=400)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'invalid request'}, status=400)

def process_data(data):
    chatID = data.get('waId')
    msg = data.get('text')
    
    if chatID and msg:
        try:
            track_obj, created = Track.objects.get_or_create(id=chatID)
            handle_message(track_obj, created, chatID, msg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing data: {str(e)}")

def handle_message(track_obj, created, chatID, msg):
    if created:
        track_obj.status = "welcome"
        welcome_message = 'Welcome to AFC Insurance! I am here to assist you with any insurance-related queries or concerns. Whether you are looking for policy information, claims assistance, or need guidance, feel free to ask. Your peace of mind is our priority! How can I help you today?'
        sendMessage(chatID, welcome_message)
        options_message = "Choose an option:\n1. Register Vehicle\n2. Make a Claim\n3. Lodge a Complaint"
        sendMessage(chatID, options_message)
        track_obj.status = "home"
        track_obj.save()
    elif track_obj.status == "home":
        # Handle other cases for track_obj.status == "home"
        pass
```

i tried everything i know in the book but its not showing any errors but its not sending any resonse.